# Arithmetic overflow error when converting numeric(9,2) to numeric(9,3)

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to add another decimal point in my database and I keep getting this error in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (2014). The column is currently numeric(9, 2) NULL and I want to change it to numeric(9, 3) NULL. Either by code or the designer, it won't allow me to do this.

```
ALTER TABLE LOG ALTER COLUMN WEIGHT numeric(9, 3) NULL

-- Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
```

After reading several threads I didn't manage to find an answer to this question. Since I'm only making the field bigger, there should be no truncation problems or the likes in theory.

The biggest value in the table is 1102439.00 and the smallest is 0.00. Not a single NULL.

Comment: Since your biggest value length is `9` and you are trying to define its scale to `3` which is make its length to `10` digit, to avoid such situation try to define NUMERIC(10,3), this may solve your problem

Comment: @JaydipJ This solved my problem actually.

Comment: To provide some more info on the solution: You are not making the field bigger you are only moving the decimal point. Any 9 digit number will fail e.g. 1102439.00 as this will need to be 1102439.000 which is 10 digits long.

Comment: @JaydipJ Could you please add this as an answer so I can mark it as a solution?

Comment: Ok nop I will do it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your biggest value length is `9` and you are trying to define its scale to `3` which is make its length to 10 digit which is not fitted in `NUMERIC(9,3)`,

Since `NUMERIC(P,S)` where,

- P is Precision which shows total number of digits
- S is Scale which indicated total number of digits after decimal

To avoid such situation try to define `NUMERIC(10,3)`, this may solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

1. When you already define it as NUMERIC(10,3) which is equivalent to DECIMAL(10,3), you're using precision *p* in the range 10-19 that is occupying 9 Bytes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx). Use instead DECIMAL(19,3) so that you'll get the max values with the same storage for the column.